# Issue while applying aggregate functions like count,sum on columns having null values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

We have the following input dataframe.

df1

---

### Dep      |Gender|Salary|DOB                |Place

Finance  |Male  |5000  |2009-02-02 00:00:00|UK

HR       |Female|6000  |2006-02-02 00:00:00|null

HR       |Male  |14200 |null               |US

IT       |Male  |null  |2008-02-02 00:00:00|null

IT       |Male  |55555 |2008-02-02 00:00:00|UK

Marketing|Female|12200 |2005-02-02 00:00:00|UK

---

Used the following code to find the count:

```
    df = df1.groupBy(df1['Dep'])
    df2 =  df.agg({'Salary':'count'})
    df2.show()
```

The result is:

---

### Dep      |count(Salary)

Finance  |1

HR       |2

Marketing|1

IT       |1

---

The expected result is shown below.

---

### Dep      |count(Salary)

Finance  |1

HR       |2

Marketing|1

IT       |2

---

Here issue comes with 4-th row data, where Salary data is null. And count operation on null is not working.

Appreciate your help in solving this issue.

Comment: What do you want to do null values in salary column?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace null values:

```
df \
    .na.fill({'salary':0}) \
    .groupBy('Dep') \
    .agg({'Salary':'count'})
```

Comment: But after filling null values with Zero, other aggregate operations on data like average,minimum value will be wrong. And what should we do if the column is a date type with null value? We can't fill date column with Zero value. The main issue with filling null values is that, it will change the data and will affect the subsequent operations.